# Using sed with html data

Tags: bash, sed, pattern-matching

I'm having some problems using sed in combination with html. The following sample illustrates the problem:

```
HTML="<html><body>ENTRY</body><html>"
TABLE="<table></table>"
echo $HTML | sed -e s/ENTRY/$TABLE/
```

This outputs:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'
```

If I leave out the `/` from `$TABLE` so that it becomes `<table><table>` it works ok.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

**Update**
Here's a sample that can reproduce the problem:

template.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            ENTRIES
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

gui_template:

```
<tr>
  <td class="td_tut_title">TITLE</td>
  <td class="td_tut_content">
    <a href="../tutorials/GUI/FILENAME"><img src="img/bbp.png" alt="bbp" /></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

genhtml.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
HTML=`cat template.html`
ENTRIES=`cat gui_template | sed -e s/FILENAME/test/ | sed -e s/TITLE/title/`
DELIM=$'\377'
echo $HTML | sed -e "s${DELIM}ENTRIES${DELIM}$ENTRIES${DELIM}"
```

Output:

```
~/htmlgen $ ./genhtml.sh 
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different delimiter @ for example

```
echo $HTML | sed -e s@ENTRY@$TABLE@
```

Comment: That didn't work on my FreeBSD box however until I've put it in apostrophes `sed 's@ENTRY@$TABLE@'` or echoed a dollar sign `sed s@ENTRY@\$TABLE@`.

Comment: It works for the sample above, but it failed when processing an entire html file.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: How did it fail?

Comment: With exactly the same error message: "unterminated `s' command".

Comment: @StackedCrooked: Your variable contains character that is used as sed delimiter. Try using a delimiter char that is not used inside your file.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: This time you have a problem with newlines in replacement. This fixed it:

ENTRIES=`cat gui_template | sed -e s/FILENAME/test/ | sed -e s/TITLE/title/ | sed 's/$/\\\\n/' | tr -d '\n'`

If you are not stuck to bash it maybe easier to use some other scripting language.

BTW in case you don't know you can use #!/bin/bash -x
to see what bash is really doing.

Answer (score 1):

Issuing these lines on FreeBSD console:

```
HTML="<html><body>ENTRY</body></html>"
TABLE="<table></table>"
echo $HTML | sed -e "s#ENTRY#$TABLE#"
```

Result in:

```
<html><body><table></table></body></html>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry I jumped to conclusions too fast. With the single quotes the variables aren't dereferenced anymore.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: `echo $HTML | sed -e "s#ENTRY#$TABLE#"` works for me.

Comment: It seems to work like this like this in a smaller sample, but not in the final script which processes a bigger html file. I'll do some more research..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delimiter that can't appear in $TABLE, and if $TABLE is unpredictable enough this can be tricky.  I'd suggest using a nonprinting character as a delimiter; it's easier to find one that's not going to show up in $TABLE and break everything.  The only problem is they're harder to type in, so I'd suggest putting it in a variable and using that in the sed command:

```
DELIM=$'\377'
HTML="<html><body>ENTRY</body><html>"
TABLE="<table></table>"
echo "$HTML" | sed -e "s${DELIM}ENTRY${DELIM}$TABLE${DELIM}"
```

Note that the `$'...'` construct is a bash-only feature; if you need this to run under generic sh you'll have to do something messier, like `DELIM="$(printf "\377")"`.  Also, I chose \377 (that's FF in hex) because it's illegal in the UTF-8 encoding, so it should be safe if you're using UTF-8 for your HTML; if you're using something else, like Windows-1252, then \177 (the 'DEL' character) might be a safer choice.

Oh, yeah, and if you ever try to debug this with `bash -x`, be prepared for comedy.

Comment: I still can't get it to work, I updated my post with a code sample.